# How can I get the QuickContactBadge to show an action for sending Instant Messages?

Tags: contacts, instant-messaging, intents

I'm wondering if there are any instant messaging apps which link to contact data fields and use intents to add a `Send Instant Message` action to the QuickContactBadge shown in many places when clicking on a contact.

I remember the Samsung-added (or was it AT&T-added, I don't remember) IM app that came OEM on my Galaxy S Captivate way back did this.

Are there any IM apps in the market that will allow me to click on a contact, pop-open the QuickContactBadge and then send an IM right from there?